# Why does my Colab session run out of RAM?

Tags: python, keras, computer-vision, google-colaboratory, h5py

I'm building a model for image deblurring based on the model described in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.07064) using Keras. I train the model on Colab using the following training code:

```
x_train, y_train = load_h5_dataset()

def train(batch_size=16, epoch_num=5, critic_updates=5, log_dir='drive/MyDrive/train_logs'):
    g = make_resnet_generator_model()
    d = make_discriminator_model()
    gan = make_gan(g, d)

    d_opt = Adam(learning_rate=1e-4, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-8)
    gan_opt = Adam(learning_rate=1e-4, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-8)

    d.trainable = True
    d.compile(optimizer=d_opt, loss=wasserstein_loss)
    d.trainable = False
    loss = [perceptual_loss, wasserstein_loss]
    loss_weights = [100, 1]
    gan.compile(optimizer=gan_opt, loss=loss, loss_weights=loss_weights)
    d.trainable = True

    output_true_batch, output_false_batch = np.ones((batch_size, 1)), -np.ones((batch_size, 1))
    writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(log_dir)

    for epoch in tqdm(range(epoch_num)):
        print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{epoch_num}...")
    
        permuted_indexes = np.random.permutation(x_train.shape[0])

        d_losses = []
        gan_losses = []
        x_train = dataset['sharp_img']
        for index in range(int(x_train.shape[0] / batch_size)):
            batch_indexes = permuted_indexes[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size]
            image_blur_batch = x_train[batch_indexes]
            image_full_batch = y_train[batch_indexes]

            generated_images = g.predict(x=image_blur_batch, batch_size=batch_size)

            for _ in range(critic_updates):
                d_loss_real = d.train_on_batch(image_full_batch, output_true_batch)
                d_loss_fake = d.train_on_batch(generated_images, output_false_batch)
                d_loss = 0.5 * np.add(d_loss_fake, d_loss_real)
                d_losses.append(d_loss)

            d.trainable = False

            gan_loss = gan.train_on_batch(image_blur_batch, [image_full_batch, output_true_batch])
            gan_losses.append(gan_loss)

            d.trainable = True

    write_logs(writer, ['d_loss', 'gan_loss'], [np.mean(d_losses), np.mean(gan_losses)], epoch)
    save_weights(d, g, epoch, int(np.mean(gan_losses)))
```

In the training code above, the perceptual loss is calculated using a VGG16 network, pretrained on ImageNet. The function `load_h5_dataset()` is used to load a dataset saved as a .hdf5 file. I encounter two problems when executing this code:

1. When I run it on Colab, it keeps running out of RAM on Colab and stops the execution. However, the size of the dataset is 6GB, which is well below the available size of RAM of Colab.
2. When I run this code on my local machine (which has 16GB of RAM and a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti with 6GB capacity), I encounter this error: `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[16,256,128,128] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc [Op:Conv2D]`

Can someone have a look at my code and see what going wrong here? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this issue https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1993

And also you can

`del whatevervariable`

and then RAM will be free

Comment: I've tried both reducing batch size and deleting the redundant arrays, however the problem persists.